# Prevent tab change if validation fails - easyResponsiveTabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have implemented easyResponsiveTabs in my application. In every tab I have used AjaxBeginForm to post my data. I am saving my data while changing tab by clicking hidden save button.

I want to prevent tab change if validation fails. Is there any options available.
I am saving my data as per below code while changing tab:

```
 $('#ulTab').on("click", "li", function (event) {
        var activeTab = $(this).find('a').data("tabid");           
        var hdnActivetabIndex = $("#hdnActivetabIndex");
        $("#hdnActivetabIndex").val('');
        var btnsave = $("#btnsavetab");
        if (btnsave != null && hdnActivetabIndex != null && btnsave.prop("disabled") == false) {
            hdnActivetabIndex.val(activeTab);
            btnsave.click();
        }
        else {
             Tab_Change(activeTab);
        }

    });
$('#divTabs').easyResponsiveTabs({
        type: 'default', //Types: default, vertical, accordion
        width: 'auto', //auto or any width like 600px
        fit: true, // 100% fit in a container
        tabidentify: 'horz_1', // The tab groups identifier
        activate: function (event) { // Callback function if tab is switched
            var $tab = $(this);
            var $info = $('#nested-tabInfo');
            var $name = $('span', $info);
            $name.text($tab.text());
            $info.show();
        }
    });
```

Here on button clicked form submitted.

Comment: there are many tabs and each have their own validation function. But in common I returned false if validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Add return false to stop propagation.

I suggest you to change your selector to `$('#ulTab li')` too.

```
$('#ulTab li').click(function (event) {
    var activeTab = $(this).find('a').data("tabid");           
    var hdnActivetabIndex = $("#hdnActivetabIndex");
    $("#hdnActivetabIndex").val('');
    var btnsave = $("#btnsavetab");
    if (btnsave != null && hdnActivetabIndex != null && btnsave.prop("disabled") == false) {
        hdnActivetabIndex.val(activeTab);
        btnsave.click();
        return false;
    }
    else {
         Tab_Change(activeTab);
    }

});
```

Comment: I have returned false, but  when as another tab clicked that tab displays as selected

Comment: I don't know exactly what plugin are you using, but the idea is to stop the event propagation to the plugin event handler. You can do this returning false or using event.StopPropagation() and event.StopImmediatePropagation(). Preventing the event propagation the plugin will not take any action and will keep your tab intact.

Comment: I have used easyResponsiveTabs